# Angularjs multiple app can't route a subapplication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a site with multiple angularjs app inside. The structure is the following :

```
index.html
js
      js_controller.js
      js_directives.js
      js_filters.js
      js_routes.js
      js_home.js
sub_app
   index.html
   js
      subapp_controller.js
      subapp_directives.js
      subapp_filters.js
      subapp_routes.js
      subapp_home.js
```

On the first app I added the following in js_routes.js :

```
angular.module('jsroutes.routes', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'templates/mytemplates.html'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }])
```

No problem with this. It works well.
The problem concern my subapp. I added the following in subapp_routes.js :

```
angular.module('subapproutes.routes', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/subapp', {templateUrl: '/subapp/templates/mytemplate.html', controller: 'myCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.when('/subapp/:id', {templateUrl: '/subapp/templates/mysecond.html', controller: 'myCtrl'});
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/subapp'});
    }])
```

The problem is : if the url is /subapp works, /subapp/1 not work for example. It returns to home with templates/mytemplates.html

I don't know why.

If someone can help me.
Thanks in advance